# JasperReports: subreport with different orientation

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

Is it possible to combine portrait and landscape oriented subreports in a single report? I'm using iReport 2.0.4, and can't seem to find any option to do that.

Comment: In what context would that be reasonable?

Comment: The report is mostly portrait oriented, but the last page (subreport) is a huge table that fits only in a landscape oriented page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think it's possible.

All subreports follow the orientation of the main report.

Answer (score 0):

You can simulate it by just rotating the texts, changing the orientation and the print order on your desired own

I did it with a portrait oriented main report and a landscape subreport

You may need a jump page (break element) before subreport