# portrait and landscape pages in same jasper report

Tags: jasper-reports

Hello I'm new to jasper reports, I would like to know if it is posible to have a portrait and lanscape oriented pages in the same report?

Or do you need to create two separate reports (one landscape and one portrait) for this and merge them together afterwords?

Comment: I don't know of any metodo since you need to state height and width in report properties su I guess you need to merge them later...use multiple jasper print...

Comment: Tnx for the hint I was having hte same thoughts and I will porbbably go on that way.

Comment: If you post and answer with some code on how you merged them later, it would surely be appricated by the community, and if you comment here when done you will have my up vote...

Answer (score 1):

If you have a main report (choose landscape or portrait), using subreports, you can apply for each subreport its layout with property `orientation` in root tag `jasperReport`, as follow

```
<jasperReport ... orientation = "Landscape" ... />
```

or

```
<jasperReport ... orientation = "Portrait" ... />
```

Comment: This did not work for me. Orientation is ignored, if the main report has another orientation. See also [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2147304/jasperreports-subreport-with-different-orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2147304/jasperreports-subreport-with-different-orientation)

Answer (score 0):

It does not seem like it is possible. The closest thing to this behaviour is a [report book](https://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/tibco-jaspersoft-studio-user-guide/v60/report-books). Seen in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39639199/2351407).